# How to generate keccak256(STRING,INTEGER) from Javascript?

Tags: solidity, truffle, sha3, keccak

In my solidity code I use `bytes32` generated by 
`keccak256("STRING_VALUE',INTEGER)` 
to store values in the map.

One of the sample values that get generated is

`0x728021dd1e605706a029ef0f0a96028fab0d170608cbfcc8b28ff7786d985dcf`

Now I want to generate this hash in my JS code, I have tried using libraries like `js-sha3`, `keccak`, `solidity-sha3`. None of them take Integer as a parameter and also they return hash that is irrelevant to what is generated above.

How do I generate similar hash in the JS?

Answer (score 3):

Simple convert your integer into base 16, and append to original string finally calculate hash. It will be same.

```
function solSha3 (...args) {
    args = args.map(arg => {
        if (typeof arg === 'string') {
            if (arg.substring(0, 2) === '0x') {
                return arg.slice(2)
            } else {
                return web3.toHex(arg).slice(2)
            }
        }

        if (typeof arg === 'number') {
            return leftPad((arg).toString(16), 64, 0)
        } else {
          return ''
        }
    })

    args = args.join('')

    return '0x' + web3.sha3(args, { encoding: 'hex' })
}
```

For more details refer [Github link](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/445)